# SQL Count events with duration per hour

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, mariadb

I have data of an event with duration (say, eating a meal at a restaurant) and I want to know for any given hour how many events were taking place. The data looks like this:

```
Event     |   Start Time    |   End Time
-----------------------------------------
  1       |   12:03         |   14:20
  2       |   12:30         |   12:50
  3       |   13:05         |   14:45
  4       |   14:01         |   14:49
```

I also have "Duration" available as an alternative to "End Time". The result I'm looking for would be like this:

```
  Hour     |     Count
-----------------------
   12      |     2
   13      |     2
   14      |     3
```

During hour 12, there were two events happening (1 & 2), hour 13 also had two events (1 & 3) and hour 14 had three events (1, 3, & 4).

I can do this programmatically with a loop. I can count when the events *start* (or *end*) in SQL. But I'd really like to bridge the gap and do this in SQL, but I can't think of a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution (works with MySQL v5.6+ and SQLite3):

```
create table hours(Hour int);
insert into hours values
  (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
  (13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23);

create table log(Event int,StartTime varchar(5),EndTime varchar(5));
insert into log values
  (1,'12:03','14:20'),
  (2,'12:30','12:50'),
  (3,'13:05','14:45'),
  (4,'14:01','14:49');

-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select Hour,count(Event) Count
  from log join hours
    on Hour between substr(StartTime,1,2) and substr(EndTime,1,2)
  group by Hour;
```

Comment: Clever! This will work until I can get my ISP to update Maria DB and use @GMB's solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you could use `UNION ALL`, window functions and aggregation, like so:

```
select hr, sum(sum(cnt)) over(order by hr) cnt
from (
    select hour(start_time) hr, 1 cnt from mytable
    union all select hour(end_time) + 1, -1 from mytable
) t
group by hr
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24228996086ea950e170a6e2d6be92ac)**:

```
hr | cnt
-: | --:
12 |   2
13 |   2
14 |   3
15 |   0
```

Comment: Wonderful! Now I just need to get my ISP to upgrade to MariaDB 10.2. They're still on 10.1, *just* before Window Functions were introduced. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have MySql 8, then create a table `hour`:

```
CREATE TABLE hour (
  hr INT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO hour(hr) VALUES
    (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),
    (12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23);
```

And then:

```
select h.hr, count(*) as cnt from hour h
join mytable m on h.hr between hour(m.Start_Time) and hour(m.End_Time)
group by hr
order by hr
;
```

[See Db-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oV3z3BAJSERx1FvHgexgZ5/0)